# Window size it's not working correctly in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have made a python program that moves a square and haves gravity, and every thing works fine, except the "window_size" part. It shows the right size at first, but after less than a second, it goes to another window size. Don't really know why it does this, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
import pygame, sys

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 350

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('gravity movement')

window_size = (800, 600)#here is the problem
window_screen = pygame.display.set_mode(window_size)

window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = pygame.Rect(30, 30, 32, 32)
player_speed = 5


#movement
def move(rect, x, y):
    rect.x += x
    rect.y += y

#Add gravity
def gravity(rect, g_force= 4):
    rect.y += g_force
    if rect.y + rect.h >= HEIGHT:
        rect.y = HEIGHT - rect.h


x, y = 0,0

while True:
    clock.tick(60)#means that for every second (at most) 60 frames should pass

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x = -player_speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x = player_speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y = -20
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y = 0
        
        
    #Draw
    window.fill((0, 0, 20))
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 24, 10), player)

    #definitive movement
    move(player, x= x, y=y)
    gravity(player)
    
   
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Are you aware that you call `pygame.display.set_mode` twice? The final size of the window is the size you passed to the 2nd call (500, 500).

Answer (score 0):

you call `pygame.display.set_mode` twice. The final size of the window is the size you passed to the 2nd call (500, 500).